# Android: any buildToolsVersion for Gradle config

Tags: android, gradle

Is it possible to use wildcard for version, or omit the version of buildToolsVersion altogether? We have a large team with people having various versions of android tools, so hardcoding a specific release number  in the gradle config file (i.e. "22.0.1") breaks the build.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have your team synchronize on the build tools version? That's what every large team that I have ever heard of does. The point of having `buildToolsVersion` (along with `compileSdkVersion`, detailed dependencies, Android for Gradle plugin version, and Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`) is to be able to reproduce a build.

Comment: @CommonsWare specifying tools version is like demanding that you must compile your project only with GCC 4.7.1/binutils 2.18.1 lol